# Unable to Register Autofill service in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, autofill

It's not showing in my phone's System>Language & Input>Advanced settings> Autofill after putting the service in the manifest and giving the required permissions recommended in android Autofill framework documentation.

Manifest File

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".Filler"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTO_FILL">

        <meta-data android:name="android.autofill"
            android:resource="@xml/filler"/>

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>
```

Do i need to implement some method into my MainActivity Class to get it registered into the Autofill service?

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro, but: Nothing needed in MainActivity. Your declaration seems fine. I guess you also created a class for your service?

```
class MyAutofillService : AutofillService() {
    override fun onFillRequest(
        request: FillRequest,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
        callback: FillCallback
    ) {
        //handel fill request
        callback.onSuccess(null)
    }
}
```

I can select the service and my declaration is:

```
    <service
            android:name=".MyAutofillService"
            android:label="MyLabel"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Are there any errors when debugging the app?